# py.test fails due to missing module

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to write a test, but this test will pass only if the `nlopt` module is installed. Since this module is *optional*, I was wondering if there's a way to write a test that won't prevent py.test to fail completely if the module is not present. at this point, py.test stops as it can't find the `nlopt` module:

```
$ make test
py.test --exitfirst tests/
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.4.2 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
collecting 0 items / 1 errors
=================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================
_____________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/fem/test_simulation.py ______________________________________________
tests/unit/fem/test_simulation.py:5: in <module>
    from hybrida.fem import Simulation, Step, Eigenvalue
src/hybrida/__init__.py:4: in <module>
    from . import geometry
src/hybrida/geometry/__init__.py:3: in <module>
    from . import distance
src/hybrida/geometry/distance.py:9: in <module>
    import nlopt
E   ImportError: No module named 'nlopt'
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout ---------------------------------------------------------------
 nlopt does not seem to be installed. 
=========================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================
ERROR tests/unit/fem/test_simulation.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: stopping after 1 failures !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================================================== 1 error in 0.67 seconds ===========================================================
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

I tried to add a `try-except` block in the beginning of the test file but this didn't help:

```
try:
    import nlopt
    import numpy as np

except ImportError:
    print("""nlopt does not seem to be installed""")
```

The `nlopt` module is used inside the library for which I'm writing a test. Currently, the library raises an exception if the module is not found. At the top level of a file that uses the module:

```
try:
    import nlopt

except ImportError:
    print("""\033[91m nlopt does not seem to be installed. Please install it by downloading nlopt, and installing it using
        $ ./configure --enable-shared
        $ make
        $ make install
        and adding /usr/local/lib/Python3.4/site-packages to the PYTHONPATH
        (or wherever nlopt has been installed):
        export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/Python3.4/site-packages

        Note: although Homebrew provides nlopt, it does not install the Python interface.\033[0m""")
    raise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [conditional import machinery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skipping-on-a-missing-import-dependency) pytest provides:

```
nlopt = pytest.importorskip('nlopt')
```

Put that line inside the specific test function that uses `nlopt` (or in the setup method for a set of functions) and it will only skip those when it can't do the import.

Comment: I tried that, but the code still fails inside the library for which I provided the test, as inside the library there's also an `import nlopt` that raises an exception if it can't find the module.

Comment: You can move that `import` inside the functions that actually use it, instead of having it be top-level.

Comment: You mean on the library side or on the test side?

Comment: On the library side. What does the library code do presently when `nlopt` isn't found?

Comment: I have modified my post to show you what the library currently does. It seems ugly but I don't know a better way to accomplish that. Ideally, I would like the library to work, even if the module isn't installed in the computer.

Comment: Well, if the library itself is raising `ImportError`, just change your skip: `my_library = pytest.importorskip(my_library)`. If you want your code to still work when `nlopt` is not present, you could just set something like `NO_NLOPT=True` in the `except ImportError` block, don't raise, and then have alternate code paths that do whatever workaround you need.

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: The link in the answer is now broken.